# SessionNotCreatedException - Docker in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver, webdriver-manager

I've been trying to run some Selenium tests in Jenkins by launching selenium-standalone in Docker and running all the tests in my repo through that. Everything seems to set up properly, but when it comes to actually running the tests, every single one comes back with this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException at RemoteWebDriver.java:561
    Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException at NettyHttpHandler.java:73
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at NettyConnectListener.java:179
            Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException
                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at SocketChannelImpl.java:-2
```

The driver itself is created by the following line:

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().create();
```

What might be causing this error?